# Invert a triangle from three vectors (2D)

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

How would I go, if I need to invert the area of a triangle, in 2D. Need this logic for a game. As I'm trying to mark everything but the area of the triangle.

I hope enough info is provided.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to color all the pixels outside the triangle green, or something like that?  Or do you just want to be able to tell if a point is outside the triangle?

Comment: @saulspatz, I want to tell if a certain point outside of a triangle, or rather, polygon.

Comment: If you mean polygon, not triangle, please correct your question to say that.  Someone has already spent time answering a question other than the one you meant to ask.  Now, is the polygon convex?

Comment: No, I'm using triangles, but if the same rules would apply with polygons, that'd be a plus

Comment: It *much* easier for triangles.  The point in polygon (PIP) problem is a well-known one in computer graphics, but I don't know much about it.  I think the answer that mathreadler gave you is about as good as you're going to do for triangles.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks!

Comment: @saulspatz yes it is an argument why those triangles aren't a very natural or practical representation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know some vectors and linear algebra you can transform the point you wonder if inside into the coordinate system with center in one of corners of triangle and unit axes pointing at the other corners.

Now if any one of the coordinates in the new coordinate system is negative OR the sum >1 then you are outside the triangle.

So if we have one vector pointing to one corner $\bf o$. Then two other vectors pointing to the other corners (from that corner) $\bf p_1,p_2$:

1. Calculate the matrix ${\bf T} = [{\bf p_1, p_2}]^{-1}$
2. Build matrix ${\bf M}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}{\bf T}&-{\bf T}d({\bf o}) \\ {\bf 0}& {\bf I}_2\end{array}\right]$
3. Build a vector $\bf v$ of the point you want to decide for.
4. Calculate $\bf Mv$
5. If

   1. any of the entries of $\bf Mv$ are $< 0$ OR
   2. both are positive and the sum $> 1$

Just to show it works:

[image]

Comment: I'm not as good as I should be with linear algebra, so if you'd explain the step, that'd be neat!

Comment: Oh no you tricked me to build a triangle! Dang